# change input field data in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've signup form. In input field when I used to write previous username then it gives me available username list which is coming from API.

My question is that how to change input field data when I used to click available username in vue js?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please show the code which you tried so far ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want to do something like...
User types in a username, somewhere in the UI you show a list of available usernames, user clicks preferred username, input box is updated with selected username.

Without seeing any of your code it's difficult to give you an specific answer, however, what I would do is:

1. Create the input box. Bind this to an object in your script:
   HTML:

   `<input v-model="username"/>`
   Script: `username: string = "";      availableUsernames: [""];`
2. Create a button next to the input box, when it's pressed it calls your API and returns the available usernames and applies to to availableUsernames.
3. The available usernames are returned as an array and the array is displayed on your UI as a list.
4. When you click on an object in the list on your UI, this calls a function which updates the username property. e.g.:

   `<li v-for="u in usernames"><a @click="applyUsername(u.description)`">
   `applyUsername(description: String){ this.username = description }`